# Locating HTML Tags

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to automate the testing of web forms.  To that end I need to know how to use C# to dynamically locate input tags within the HTML page then assign values to them.  I don't want to use XPath, because each time I will be using a different web form.  I want to pass the web form's URL to Selenium and then automatically populate the fields.  I've heard of HTMLAgilityPack.  Would that help me?  If so, how can I use it?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'different web form'? Are these different pages? Or do you mean different input boxes on the same page?

Comment: These are different web pages.  Each website I test is for a new client.

Comment: So basically you want magical piece of code that will look at web page, sence your intentions and than fill some fileds with values you want? I think to get some real code you need to define magic portion better (i.e. "INPUT of type text" or "hidden input checkbox" ... should be set to "42 or Fridays, 7 on all other days")

Answer (score 2):

I may have missed a crucial part of your question, however, have you looked at [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)?

If you write a test that handles a generic web form you can back your test by data that is dynamic. Therefore you can cater for changes in the page by using Data Driven Tests. I've written tests for many pages and there are always common actions, but I cater for each page differently though as there are different things on that page!

[EDIT]
Following on from your comments, I think looking into Selenium would be a good idea. The way to handle different pages is to have these element definitions ready in a 'definitions' class for each page. That way once you know what the page is, you just use the correct class for your definitions. It is best to know what elements you are going to be interacting with in your tests **before** the tests run. The point of automated UI testing is for a known set of actions to be performed and a correct result achieved.

I would suggest you look up some tutorials such as [this](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_csharp_nunit.htm) and you can see my [blog](http://nashibukasan.blogspot.com.au/)
though I wrote this when I was initially learning WatiN and then replaced it with Selenium (I like it better :P).

Comment: WebDriver is the best.. ;D

Comment: My goal is I want to automate the testing of forms on each newly built  website delivered to me by the developer.  If we were using standard naming convention for the control IDs (i.e. the "First Name" textbox on every website's registration page used first_name for the ID attribute), then I could record my actions in one registration page and use the resulting script to test any new registration page.  But, each new registration page has a new set of  control IDs.

Comment: So, I am thinking the code should look at the page, find all the controls, put them into an array, then assign a value to each array location.  But, I am not a programmer and don't know how to do that.

Comment: @user1020173, Selenium can do this for you, but only if you tell it to. You must learn programming to make automated testing successful. Dynamically created controls are not a problem, but again, given enough programming experience and skill it's easily worked around.

Comment: I have edited my answer to try address you dynamic situation a bit better :)

Answer (score 0):

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows
>   you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant
>   with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to
>   what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);

foreach (HtmlNode input in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input"))
    // Your Code...
```

Comment: +0: it is very unlikly to help OP - "locate input tags within the HTML page then assign values to them". Despite the fact that it is very unclear what the end goal is, I doubt HtmlAgilityPack would help.

Comment: The problem is that the question was not that clear. So what? A web scraping utility? http://www.teknologika.com/blog/the-holy-grail-net-automated-web-gui-testing-for-internet-explorer/ -> http://watin.org/